# HTML: Display only loading spinner for <video> and hide other controls when specify controls attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a custom video player that have custom play/pause/next button, etc. I want to display a loading spinner for my player but the only way I could come up with is to use `controls` attribute. Doing so my video can display a loading spinner but the other controls will be shown together with the spinner.
Is there a way to show only the spinner?

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming for a custom video player with a loading spinner but without the default controls showing up, here's a neat trick: skip the controls attribute on your  tag. Instead, create a custom spinner with some HTML and CSS, and position it over your video. Use JavaScript to manage the spinner's visibility—show it when the video is buffering and hide it when the video plays smoothly. This approach gives you the best of both worlds: a sleek loading spinner for your video, minus the default control clutter. It's a smart, straightforward solution for a cleaner, custom video player experience.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    const spinner = document.querySelector('.loading-spinner');

    video.addEventListener('waiting', () => {
        spinner.style.display = 'block'; // Show spinner when video is buffering
    });

    video.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
        spinner.style.display = 'none'; // Hide spinner when video can play
    });

    video.addEventListener('playing', () => {
        spinner.style.display = 'none'; // Also hide spinner when video is playing
    });
});
```

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 640px; /* Match video width */
    height: 360px; /* Match video height */
}

.loading-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px; /* Spinner size */
    height: 50px; /* Spinner size */
    background: url('path_to_your_spinner_image.gif') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <video id="myVideo" width="640" height="360">
        <source src="path_to_your_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
</div>
```

This ensures that your video player shows a loading spinner during buffer times without displaying the default browser video controls. Adjust the CSS to match the style of your site and ensure the spinner image URL is correctly set.